# Weird behavior of custom annotations views

Tags: swift, mapkit

I've built the same code in SwiftUI and Storyboard and I get the same weird issues.

Whenever I run and go to background and back to foreground, the custom views are lost.
Whenever I zoom-drag far (say 10km), I also lose the non-picture-holding pin, eg "Pencil".

I'm not sure where I've gone amiss, except maybe that I'd need to separate my pins per annotation view "type" (with a given picture, with text...) and set a different reuse identifier based on that, but it sounds weird given I'm not actually creating anything new (only setting properties of the base `MKAnnotationView` class).

Using the UIKit version as reference:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let cityMapManager = CityMapManager()
    let cityMapViewDelegate = CityMapViewDelegate()

    let places: [Place] = [Place(name: "Cathedral", location: .init(latitude: 50.640364, longitude: 3.062058))]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.640364, longitude: 3.062058), latitudinalMeters: 500.0, longitudinalMeters: 500.0), animated: false)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.showsScale = true
        mapView.delegate = cityMapViewDelegate
        annotateLocalPOI(map: mapView)
    }

    private func annotateLocalPOI(map: MKMapView) {

        var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Red Pin"
        annotation.subtitle = "I'm a pin and I'm red. Maybe, or not."
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.64, longitude: 3.06)
        // add the annotation to the map (will use red pin, mapView:viewFor: allows changing the display)
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
        annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Pencil"
        annotation.subtitle = "Will not display"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 50.642, longitude: 3.059)
        map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }    
}

struct Place: Identifiable {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    let name: String
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}

class CityMapViewDelegate: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }

        let identifier = "Annotation"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
            if annotation.title == "Red Pin" {
                let pinImage = UIImage(systemName: "timelapse")
                annotationView?.image = pinImage
            }
            if annotation.title == "Pencil" {
                // this overrules any subtitle available
                annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil"))
            }
        } else {
            // reset
            annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = nil
            annotationView?.image = nil
            // set it up again
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
            if annotation.title == "Red Pin" {
                let pinImage = UIImage(systemName: "timelapse")
                annotationView?.image = pinImage
            }
            if annotation.title == "Pencil" {
                // this overrules any subtitle available
                annotationView?.detailCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(systemName: "pencil"))
            }
        }
        return annotationView
    }
}

class CityLocationManagerDelegate: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationStatus = "Status not determined"
    var locationFixFound = false

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        // We've (at least once) gone under a certain minimum accuracy required to consider we have a "fix"
        // we could use that to reflect that information on the UI (color, shape...)
        if !locationFixFound {
            for location in locations {
                if location.horizontalAccuracy < 25.0 {
                    locationFixFound = true
            }
        }

        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                            didFailWithError error: Error) {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("Location manager stopped due to error: \(error)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                         didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        print("Authorization Status changed")
        var shouldRequestLocationUpdates = false

        switch status {
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.restricted:
            locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.denied:
            locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
        case CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
            locationStatus = "Status not determined"
        default:
            locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
            shouldRequestLocationUpdates = true
        }

        if (shouldRequestLocationUpdates == true) {
            NSLog("Location to Allowed")
            // Start location services
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
            NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
        }
    }
}

struct CityMapManager {

    let locationDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate
    let locationManager: CLLocationManager

    init() {
        locationDelegate = CityLocationManagerDelegate()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = locationDelegate
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}
```

and a storyboard that holds a fullscreen map within a class set to `MapViewController`.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Use custom annotation images, then put app in background and foreground and the custom images are gone replaced by the default red pins.  not sure what is going on here.

Comment: @fawsha1 Ah, happy to know I'm not the only one with that problem!

Comment: I suspect that this is a bug and hopefully it will be solved when WWDC happens (all digital this year) and a new version comes out. fingers crossed.